# My json model in three.js is not working

Tags: javascript, json, import, model, three.js

**Hello!** I have [this website](http://eliasljunglov.net78.net) where I post my games. I have imported a json model and it is not rendered correct. Only 50% of the parts are visible. I have not done any textures on it yet. Anyone know this problem?

**PS: When you get to my website, press on SpaceRun**

Comment: Are you planning to make a game every week?

Comment: No :P I have made a few games but I only publish a few of them on my website. 
About the rendering problem can u help me?

Comment: I don't see a problem there, there are no errors in the console. Looks like everything is working?